# find command and inverse regex

Tags: regex, find, exec, inverse

I've looking for a way to express this command that excludes all executable perms except for those files ended in ".EXE"

I've trying to solve it using the "find" command and -exec, please. Thanks.

The command I tryed, and other versions of the same, does not work:

```
find . -type f -regex "[^\.EXE$]" -printf "%f\n" -exec chmod a-x {} +
```

Thanks any help, Beco.

---

Edited:

To find a "inverse" of a regular expression, I tried after (more) research:

```
find . -type f ! -regex ".EXE$" -printf "%f\n" -exec chmod a-x {} +
```

But this also did not work.

Comment: If you want to use -regex predicate, not the -name predicate, you need  to specify a regular expression, that matches the whole name: -regex ".*\.EXE$"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are few things that can be fixed with your command

First the exclusion condition. To exclude "*.EXE" say `! -name "*.EXE"`. The condition in the OP takes all files that contain a letter different from `\`,`.`, `E` or `X`.

The other thing is that for this specific purpose it makes sense to check only executable files. This can be accomplished with the `-executable` predicate.

The rest of it seems ok.

Here is a complete version

```
 find -executable -type f ! -name "*.EXE"  -exec chmod a-x {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a long time, but I would just like to share my approach here.

I completely agree with @Dima Chubarov 's approach, however also the following can be done:

```
find . -type f ! -regex ".*\.EXE$" | xargs chmod a-x
```

Note that here we are negating the regex pattern (with `!` before `-regex`) instead of trying "not to match" the pattern `.EXE` (using the regex `[^\.EXE$]`, which actually does not do what you need, as @Dima said

> The condition in the OP takes all files that contain a letter different from `\`,`.`, `E` or `X`.

)

Regarding the `xargs` command, at least for me, is more intuitive than using the `-exec` flag, and it works perfectly fine when coupled to `find` command.

Comment: Thanks. May be useful for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

if `find . -name "*.EXE" -exec chmod a-x {} +` doesn't work, then I'd just "find . -name .. -print" into a script and edit the script.